# How to force single/orphan letters to next line?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

I want to automatically change:

```
blah blah blah b
blah blah blah
```

into:

```
blah blah blah 
b blah blah blah
```

in the whole document and keep it like that.

I could insert a hard space before each and every single/orphan letter at the end of the line, but it would take lots of time and also, after slightly modifying text, it would shuffle and cause the same problem again.

Is it possible to automatically force those letters to the next line?

Comment: Please give an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you are hoping to achieve.  Also, this is more appropriate for https://superuser.com as it does not involve programming.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than inserting a space before the character, select the space *following* the character instead.  Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to prevent a line break in that location.

[image: insert non-breaking space]

The result:

[image: b is wrapped to next line]

To do this for all occurrences in the document:

- *Edit -> Find and Replace*.
- **Find**: `([:space:][:alnum:])[:space:]`
- **Replace**: `$1\u00a0`.  However, [\u syntax does not currently work for replace](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=106137), so where it says `\u00a0`, copy and paste a non-breaking space character instead.
- Enable *Other Options -> Regular Expressions.*
- Replace All.

Related: https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/134113/how-to-detect-non-breakable-space-when-iterating-document-via-uno/

Comment: Right, however if I will modify text on the beginning then everything will fall apart. Can I force LibreOffice to manage this issue and not me (as a human)?

Comment: "Can I force LibreOffice to manage this issue."  Yes... by adding a non-breaking space character.  I'm fairly certain that is the only way (see [here](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/140281/optional-character-properties/) for another way that does not work).  "If I will modify text on the beginning then everything will fall apart."  If you add another "blah" then it will wrap appropriately.  Perhaps you could give another example of a case where it does not work correctly.

Comment: Adding a non-breaking space changes the semantics of the document while the question is about formatting. This answer is at best a workaround and is not a reliable solution: remembering to manually run a "replace all" step to get proper formatting should not be required.